# Making a map overlap a DTM and export to 3D object

Tags: three.js, mapping, qgis, 3d-modelling, uv-mapping

I would like to know if anyone knows how to make a map overlap a DTM (digital terrain model) ou DEM.

For my part, I used QGIS plugins openLayers and QGIS2Threejs. The problem with this method lies in the resulting 3D model export : no UV is exported, I only get a .dae and a .png files (no mtl file to link them). So when I load the .dae file in 3DS Max, the texture is nowhere to be found. I have to add it manually and make the UV mapping myself... But there is nothing precise in that. 
Only then can I export a folder containg .max, .mtl and .png files, and proceed to the next steps.

Does anyone know another method, more accurate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I merged the DEM and the image texture using Blender.
See [this post](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS).
The problem with this method is that I don't have access to the coordinates anymore... since the DEM is now a 3D object.